# Making JXTreeTable Editable

Tags: swing, swingx, jxtreetable

Can anyone provide a concrete example of how to make a JXTreeTable editable?
Specifically, I would like to make all cells in one column editable. It does not appear to be the case that this functionality is supported out of the box.

Comment: should work, just make sure your treeTableModel returns true for isEditable(node, column) - the default may be false, forgot ;-) If that's the case and still not working, posst an SSCCE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JXTreeTable` has all the functionality of a regular `JTable`, so you can use the [`setCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setCellEditor%28javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor%29) and [`setDefaultEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor%29) methods. So start looking for a concrete example of an editable `JTable` and you can use (more or less) the same code

Comment: Thanks, and not setting isEditable(false) helps a lot too :-)